# "while I was in Rome I ate pasta" or "I have eaten pasta"?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

What's the correct sentence?

a) I have  been to Rome and while I was there I ate pasta.
b) I have been to Rome and while I was there I have eaten pasta.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it)

Comment: is it possible to find the answer to this question in the canonical  post,  I struggled!

Answer (score 2):

A relatively simple way to determine whether the present perfect is possible in a given clause is to look for time phrases in the clause and if they are found, whether they *exclude the present*. Any time phrase that excludes the present will mean that the present perfect cannot be used in that clause. *while I was there* refers to the past, so the present perfect **have eaten** cannot be used in that clause.   *Two days **ago**, I ate pizza.*

> I have been to Rome and *while I was there* I <strike>have eaten</strike> **ate** pasta.

You will sometimes need to refer to the speech context to make the determination. For example, if it is 10AM, "this morning" refers to the morning you are *in now*, refers to the present.  But if it is 4PM, 16:00 hours,  "this morning" refers to the *past*:

> It is 4PM now and getting close to dinner time, and I am starting to feel hungry, but I won't choose pizza because I **ate** pizza *this morning*.

In the same way, if the time phrase in the clause does not exclude the present, the present perfect is not excluded as an option:

> It is 4PM now and getting close to dinner time, and I am starting to feel hungry, so I think I'll have a slice of pizza even though I **have eaten** pizza *already today*.